# Why append works only the last time of the iteration of my code?

Tags: jquery, html

I am recreating a table from another table. I know it's not good what I am doing, but was not my decision.

I am iterating through each table and taking the information I need to create the new table. This is the function that creates the header for the new table.

```
function setTableHeader(table, oldTableName, newTableName) {
    table.html($('<thead />'));

    var firstRow = $('<tr><th></th></tr>');
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $('#'+oldTableName+' .budget-inner-table').each(function() {
        var insideText = $(this).find('h3').eq(0).text();
        //console.log(insideText);
        var column = $('<th></th>').text(insideText);
        row.append(column);
    })

    $('table#'+newTableName+' thead').append(firstRow).append(row);

}
```

And here is the result of my new table. I don't understand why the header on the last table is empty.

```
<section id="budget-overview-result">
  <table id="july-2014">
    <thead>
      <tr><th></th></tr>
      <tr>
        <th>July 2014 - Media</th>
        <th>July 2014 - Facebook</th>
        <th>Budgetplanning Online Marketing</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>

  <table id="august-2014">
    <thead></thead>
  </table>
```

Comment: Because you are appending only once

Answer (score 1):

Appending should happen inside the each loop :)

```
function setTableHeader(table, oldTableName, newTableName) {
table.html($('<thead />'));

var firstRow = $('<tr><th></th></tr>');
var row = $('<tr></tr>');
$('#'+oldTableName+' .budget-inner-table').each(function() {
    var insideText = $(this).find('h3').eq(0).text();
    //console.log(insideText);
    var column = $('<th></th>').text(insideText);
    row.append(column);
    $('table#'+newTableName+' thead').append(firstRow).append(row);

});


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found what I was doing wrong. It wasn't the append in the loop. When I create the thead for the table I needed to call the table in the loop. Like this:

So Instead of

```
table.html($('<thead />'));
```

Is

```
$('table#'+newTableName).html($('<thead />'));
```